# How do I iterate through all the cities inside this for loop before breaking? Right now it's only iterating through one

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I know my first break statement is in the wrong place, just want to illustrate what I'm trying to do with this practice problem.  How do I get the if statement to iterate through all of the cities in my array inside the for loop?  It's only iterating through the first one (which I understand -- it's iterating once and then breaking).  The goal is to iterate through all of the cities and then break after returning any of the cities in the array.

```
function cityInput(city) {
  var cityToCheck = prompt("Enter your city");
  cityToCheck = cityToCheck.toLowerCase();
  var cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santa fe", "tucson", "great falls", "honolulu"];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (cityToCheck === cleanestCities[i]) {
      alert("It's one of the cleanest cities");
      break;
    } else {
      alert("city not listed");
      break;
    }
  }
};

cityInput();
```

Comment: Duh, bro, I put that there for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an default value for the alert and break only if you found the city.

```js
function cityInput(city) {
    var cityToCheck = prompt("Enter your city"),
        cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santa fe", "tucson", "great falls", "honolulu"],
        msg = "city not listed";

    cityToCheck = cityToCheck.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (cityToCheck === cleanestCities[i]) {
            msg = "It's one of the cleanest cities";
            break;
        }
    }
    alert(msg);
};

cityInput();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
} else {
  alert("city not listed");
  break;
}
```

you are breaking if the current city in the array is not the one which you are looking for. But, the next city could be the one you are looking for. What you should do is look through the entire array before coming to this conclusion. For example, you can do

```
var cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santa fe", "tucson", "great falls", "honolulu"];
var foundCity = false;
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (cityToCheck === cleanestCities[i]) {
        foundCity = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundCity) {
    alert("It's one of the cleanest cities");
} else {
    alert("city not listed");
}
```

---

Actually, you can use `Array.indexOf` function and write the whole function like this

```
if (cleanestCities.indexOf(cityToCheck) !== -1) {
    alert("It's one of the cleanest cities");
} else {
    alert("city not listed");
}
```

Or `Array.prototype.some`, like this

```
if (cleanestCities.some(function(currentCity) {
    return currentCity === cityToCheck;
})) {
    alert("It's one of the cleanest cities");
} else {
    alert("city not listed");
}
```

With ES6's Arrow functions, you can write the same as

```
if (cleanestCities.some((currentCity) => currentCity === cityToCheck)) {
    alert("It's one of the cleanest cities");
} else {
    alert("city not listed");
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.  Clean answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through all the cities, I believe thats an overkill. You could just used [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and implement it as shown below...

```
function cityInput(city) {
    var cityToCheck = prompt("Enter your city");
    var cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santa fe", "tucson", "great falls", "honolulu"];
    cityToCheck = cityToCheck.toLowerCase();

    if (cleanestCities.indexOf(cityToCheck) >= 0) {
        alert("It's one of the cleanest cities");
    } else {
        alert("city not listed");
    }
}

cityInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cityInput() {
  var cityToCheck = prompt("Enter your city");
  cityToCheck = cityToCheck.toLowerCase();
  var cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santa fe", "tucson", "great falls", "honolulu"];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (cityToCheck === cleanestCities[i]) {
      alert("It's one of the cleanest cities");
      return;
     }
   }
   alert("city not listed");
};
```

this should do it

Answer (score 0):

Try the method

```
localeCompare()
```

instead of the

`===` operator in the if statement.

Should probaly look something like this:

```
if (cityToCheck.localeCompare(cleanestCities[i]))
```